# Steam cannot set up steam data

Tags: steam

So, I am fairly new to xubuntu, and have just made a fresh install. I decided to get steam, so I used the Software Center to install steam, but i am encountering problems. Running steam from the start menu simply brings up a box saying:

> Couldn't set up Steam data - please contact technical support

And running it from the terminal produces:

```
alex@Craptop:~$ steam
Repairing installation, linking /home/alex/.steam/steam to /home/alex/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/alex/.steam/steam’: Is a directory
Setting up Steam content in /home/alex/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/alex/.steam/steam’: Is a directory"
```

Tried re-installing twice now, and am still getting the error saying it couldn't set up steam data.

Comment: try to reinstall steam.

Comment: Rename the folder /home/alex/.steam

Comment: Renaming the folder worked, but steam still isn't working,I will ask a new question that applies to it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could try this:

```
mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
rmdir ~/.steam/steam
ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
```

Which is essentially doing what the steam executable is trying to do, but failing.

Comment: `ln -s ~/.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam` ?

Comment: @mcalex What's your question? Is it about using `../.local/…` instead of `~/.local/…`? Both work fine in this case. The former creates a relative link (relative to the link location), and the later creates an absolute one. Personally, I prefer relative ones, because they will keep working even if mount the filesystem on a different path, or if I copy/move the entire directory structure.

Comment: OK, gotcha.  I thought the ../ version needed to be invoked from a certain directory and that hadn't been specified.

Comment: Worked like a charm on 18.04. Thanks!

Comment: also works on other Linux, just did this on openSUSE

Answer (score 15):

I know it's been a while and you've probably solved the problem already, but here is a fix that also works.

This error can result if you HAD Steam installed, then did a "nuke and pave" to re-install your system but had `/home` on a different partition.  When you reinstall Linux, your home directory is intact, including your Steam settings, which are in the `~/.steam` directory.  Remove the directory by opening the terminal and typing:

```
cd ~
rm -rf .steam
```

This will delete the settings folder, and Steam should install normally.

Comment: Saved my day. I just updated from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and was receiving this error, with the accepted answer being of no use. This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

considering that you had already the ff:

1. `/home/.steam`
2. steam launcher

#### Steps

1. at terminal:

   ```
   $ mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
   ```
2. using GUI, goto `.steam` folder, by default its located at `/home/.steam`
3. inside the `./steam` folder, delete the steam folder.. yeah, theres still another
   steam folder inside the `./steam` folder.. just delete it.
4. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> at terminal.. `$ steam --reset` then hit enter
5. your steam should working and updating.

Answer (score 3):

In case none of these work, find out if your home is not on a drive that is mounted noexec.
If the drive was mounted with user option, noexec is implied.

If that is the case, steam will also give this error. Solution is to mount the drive with the exec option.

Example `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=3acfd832-1761-45f8-9b34-24810195172e   /home  ext4 rw,auto,user,sync,exec,dev,suid 0 1
```

Comment: That was my problem