# I need help running steam on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, steam

**When I click on Steam I get this error:**

```
Couldn't set up Steam data - please contact technical support.
```

**I am getting the same error as this person. Here is a link to question:**

[Steam cannot set up steam data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470436/steam-cannot-set-up-steam-data)

I then tried the top answer provided in the link above and show what I encountered below, but first I am going to show you the error I get when I try to run steam in the terminal.

**Here is error encountered in the terminal when I try run steam in terminal.**

```
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ steam
Repairing installation, linking /home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam to /home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam 
rm: cannot remove '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam': Is a directory   
Setting up Steam content in /home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam
rm: cannot remove '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam': Is a directory
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$
```

**Here is the top answer I talked about earlier that was in the link provided above:**

Then I try what @Denilson Sá Maia (it was his idea for another person facing the same error) said to do and nothing happens. 
Here is link: [Steam cannot set up steam data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470436/steam-cannot-set-up-steam-data)

- mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- rm -rf ~/.steam/bin

**When I did it in terminal:**

```
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
mv: cannot move '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/appcache' to '/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/appcache': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/userdata' to '/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/userdata': Directory not empty
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ rmdir ~/.steam/steam
rmdir: failed to remove '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam': Directory not empty
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
```

Here is a history of the commands I used.

- 1  nm-tool
- 2  sudo lshw -C network
- 3  nm-tool
- 4  lsb_release
- 5  lsb_release -a
- 6  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 7  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 8  sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
- 9  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 10  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine-1.7.7/ppa
- 11  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 12  cd desktop
- 13  cd DESKTOP
- 14  sudo dpkg -i wine-1.7.7.deb
- 15  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 16  sudo apt-get update
- 17  sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
- 18  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
- 19  sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
- 20  apt-cache policy nvidia-current
- 21  sudo nvidia-xconfig
- 22  sudo apt-get install steam
- 23  run sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
- 24  sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
- 25  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
- 26  sudo apt-get update
- 27  sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
- 28  steam steam://run/325610
- 29  run wine
- 30  sudo run wine
- 31  chmod +x /usr/bin/winetricks
- 32  sh winetricks
- 33  sh winetricks
- 34 su
- 35  mv winetricks /usr/bin/
- 36  wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
- 37  wine "c:\program files\steam\steam.exe"
- 38  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 39  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 40  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 41  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 42  run steam
- 43  $ mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 44  cd ~
- 45  rm -rf .steam
- 46  cd ~
- 47  rm -rf .steam
- 48  cd ~
- 49  rm -rf .steam
- 50  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 51  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 52  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 53  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 54  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 55  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 56  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 57  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 58  History 50
- 59  history 10
- 60  history 40
- 61  MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=430 %command%
- 62  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 63  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 64  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 65  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 66  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 68  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 69  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 70  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 71  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 72  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 73  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 74  steam steam
- 75  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 76  rmdir ~/.steam/steam
- 77  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 78  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 79  steam steam
- 80  history 10
- 81  history 50
- 82  steam steam://run/325610
- 83  mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
- 85  ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
- 86  rm -rf ~/.steam/bin
- 87  history 70
- 88  history 1000

Comment: The error message about `50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist` is unrelated and harmless.

Comment: Alright, thanks. What is that error? Is there also a simple solution? Haha.

Comment: You will have to ask another question for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I am not a Steam user, so all the commands below have not been tested. They should work, based on what you wrote in your question, but I cannot guarantee it.

Here's the core of the issue:

```
johnwawryk@SteamMachine:~$ mv ~/.steam/steam/* ~/.local/share/Steam/
mv: cannot move '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/appcache' to '/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/appcache': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move '/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/userdata' to '/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/userdata': Directory not empty
```

You are getting these two errors because both directories exist:

- `/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/appcache`
- `/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/appcache`

Same for the `userdata` directory:

- `/home/johnwawryk/.steam/steam/userdata`
- `/home/johnwawryk/.local/share/Steam/userdata`

**Problem is, I have no idea which directories contains valuable data, and which can be deleted.**

I suppose `userdata` contains saved games? Just in case, here are commands to save the contents of both directories in `tar` files:

```
tar -cf ~/old-steam-userdata.tar ~/.steam/steam/userdata
tar -cf ~/new-steam-userdata.tar ~/.local/share/Steam/userdata
```

Once the `tar` files have been created in your Home directory (you can check their content with the file explorer), remove the old directories:

```
rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam
```

And then you need to run this command again:

```
ln -s ../.local/share/Steam ~/.steam/steam
```